# Angular5 Universal: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: angular, docker-compose, angular5, server-side-rendering

I am working on a Angular Universal with backend API in Laravel and trying to host the app using docker-compose

So the Structure would be

> Laravel (Api http://api.app.lo)
> Angular (http://app.lo)
> nginx (Nginx Configuration)
>
> docker-compose.yml

I am getting below error message when i try to host the app using docker and not able to trace the error.

```
| {"name":"Angular","message":"Converting circular structure to JSON","path":"/","stack":"readableObjectToString()@/var/www/angular/dist/server.js:156940:63\nresolvePromise()@/var/www/angular/dist/server.js:157090:69\nresolvePromise()@/var/www/angular/dist/server.js:157056:17\n{anonymous}()@/var/www/angular/dist/server.js:157139:17\nZoneDelegate.invokeTask()@/var/www/angular/dist/server.js:156702:31\nObject.onInvokeTask()@/var/www/angular/dist/server.js:10745:33\nZoneDelegate.invokeTask()@/var/www/angular/dist/server.js:156701:36\nZone.runTask()@/var/www/angular/dist/server.js:156469:47\ndrainMicroTaskQueue()@/var/www/angular/dist/server.js:156876:35"}
angular_1   | Unhandled Promise rejection: HttpErrorResponse {
angular_1   |   headers: HttpHeaders { normalizedNames: Map {}, lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map {} },
angular_1   |   status: 0,
angular_1   |   statusText: 'Unknown Error',
angular_1   |   url: null,
angular_1   |   ok: false,
angular_1   |   name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
angular_1   |   message: 'Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error',
angular_1   |   error: 
angular_1   |    ProgressEvent {
angular_1   |      type: 'error',
angular_1   |      target: 
angular_1   |       XMLHttpRequest {
angular_1   |         onloadstart: null,
angular_1   |         onprogress: null,
angular_1   |         onabort: null,
angular_1   |         onerror: null,
angular_1   |         onload: null,
angular_1   |         ontimeout: null,
angular_1   |         onloadend: null,
angular_1   |         _listeners: [Object],
angular_1   |         onreadystatechange: null,
angular_1   |         _anonymous: undefined,
angular_1   |         readyState: 4,
angular_1   |         response: null,
angular_1   |         responseText: '',
angular_1   |         responseType: 'text',
angular_1   |         responseURL: '',
angular_1   |         status: 0,
angular_1   |         statusText: '',
angular_1   |         timeout: 0,
angular_1   |         upload: [Object],
angular_1   |         _method: 'GET',
angular_1   |         _url: [Object],
angular_1   |         _sync: false,
angular_1   |         _headers: [Object],
angular_1   |         _loweredHeaders: [Object],
angular_1   |         _mimeOverride: null,
angular_1   |         _request: null,
angular_1   |         _response: null,
angular_1   |         _responseParts: null,
angular_1   |         _responseHeaders: null,
angular_1   |         _aborting: null,
angular_1   |         _error: null,
angular_1   |         _loadedBytes: 0,
angular_1   |         _totalBytes: 0,
angular_1   |         _lengthComputable: false },
angular_1   |      currentTarget: 
angular_1   |       XMLHttpRequest {
angular_1   |         onloadstart: null,
angular_1   |         onprogress: null,
angular_1   |         onabort: null,
angular_1   |         onerror: null,
angular_1   |         onload: null,
angular_1   |         ontimeout: null,
angular_1   |         onloadend: null,
angular_1   |         _listeners: [Object],
angular_1   |         onreadystatechange: null,
angular_1   |         _anonymous: undefined,
angular_1   |         readyState: 4,
angular_1   |         response: null,
angular_1   |         responseText: '',
angular_1   |         responseType: 'text',
angular_1   |         responseURL: '',
angular_1   |         status: 0,
angular_1   |         statusText: '',
angular_1   |         timeout: 0,
angular_1   |         upload: [Object],
angular_1   |         _method: 'GET',
angular_1   |         _url: [Object],
angular_1   |         _sync: false,
angular_1   |         _headers: [Object],
angular_1   |         _loweredHeaders: [Object],
angular_1   |         _mimeOverride: null,
angular_1   |         _request: null,
angular_1   |         _response: null,
angular_1   |         _responseParts: null,
angular_1   |         _responseHeaders: null,
angular_1   |         _aborting: null,
angular_1   |         _error: null,
angular_1   |         _loadedBytes: 0,
angular_1   |         _totalBytes: 0,
angular_1   |         _lengthComputable: false },
angular_1   |      lengthComputable: false,
angular_1   |      loaded: 0,
angular_1   |      total: 0 } } ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: HttpErrorResponse {
angular_1   |   headers: HttpHeaders { normalizedNames: Map {}, lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map {} },
angular_1   |   status: 0,
angular_1   |   statusText: 'Unknown Error',
angular_1   |   url: null,
angular_1   |   ok: false,
angular_1   |   name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
angular_1   |   message: 'Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error',
angular_1   |   error: 
angular_1   |    ProgressEvent {
angular_1   |      type: 'error',
angular_1   |      target: 
angular_1   |       XMLHttpRequest {
angular_1   |         onloadstart: null,
angular_1   |         onprogress: null,
angular_1   |         onabort: null,
angular_1   |         onerror: null,
angular_1   |         onload: null,
angular_1   |         ontimeout: null,
angular_1   |         onloadend: null,
angular_1   |         _listeners: [Object],
angular_1   |         onreadystatechange: null,
angular_1   |         _anonymous: undefined,
angular_1   |         readyState: 4,
angular_1   |         response: null,
angular_1   |         responseText: '',
angular_1   |         responseType: 'text',
angular_1   |         responseURL: '',
angular_1   |         status: 0,
angular_1   |         statusText: '',
angular_1   |         timeout: 0,
angular_1   |         upload: [Object],
angular_1   |         _method: 'GET',
angular_1   |         _url: [Object],
angular_1   |         _sync: false,
angular_1   |         _headers: [Object],
angular_1   |         _loweredHeaders: [Object],
angular_1   |         _mimeOverride: null,
angular_1   |         _request: null,
angular_1   |         _response: null,
angular_1   |         _responseParts: null,
angular_1   |         _responseHeaders: null,
angular_1   |         _aborting: null,
angular_1   |         _error: null,
angular_1   |         _loadedBytes: 0,
angular_1   |         _totalBytes: 0,
angular_1   |         _lengthComputable: false },
angular_1   |      currentTarget: 
angular_1   |       XMLHttpRequest {
angular_1   |         onloadstart: null,
angular_1   |         onprogress: null,
angular_1   |         onabort: null,
angular_1   |         onerror: null,
angular_1   |         onload: null,
angular_1   |         ontimeout: null,
angular_1   |         onloadend: null,
angular_1   |         _listeners: [Object],
angular_1   |         onreadystatechange: null,
angular_1   |         _anonymous: undefined,
angular_1   |         readyState: 4,
angular_1   |         response: null,
angular_1   |         responseText: '',
angular_1   |         responseType: 'text',
angular_1   |         responseURL: '',
angular_1   |         status: 0,
angular_1   |         statusText: '',
angular_1   |         timeout: 0,
angular_1   |         upload: [Object],
angular_1   |         _method: 'GET',
angular_1   |         _url: [Object],
angular_1   |         _sync: false,
angular_1   |         _headers: [Object],
angular_1   |         _loweredHeaders: [Object],
angular_1   |         _mimeOverride: null,
angular_1   |         _request: null,
angular_1   |         _response: null,
angular_1   |         _responseParts: null,
angular_1   |         _responseHeaders: null,
angular_1   |         _aborting: null,
angular_1   |         _error: null,
angular_1   |         _loadedBytes: 0,
angular_1   |         _totalBytes: 0,
angular_1   |         _lengthComputable: false },
angular_1   |      lengthComputable: false,
angular_1   |      loaded: 0,
angular_1   |      total: 0 } } undefined
```

Below is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  laravel:
    build: ./laravel/docker/php
    depends_on:
      - database
    expose:
      - 9000  
    volumes:
      - ./laravel:/var/www/laravel
      - $HOME/.composer/:$HOME/.composer/
    environment:
      - "DB_HOST=database"    #mysql service name - database
      - "DB_DATABASE=homestead"
      - "DB_USERNAME=homestead"
      - "DB_PASSWORD=homestead"
      - "REDIS_HOST=cache"
      - "REDIS_PORT=6379"
      - "APP_URL=http://app.lo"

  angular:
    build: ./angular
    expose:
      - 3000
    volumes:
      - ./angular:/var/www/angular 
    depends_on:
      - laravel

  web:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    links:
      - laravel:laravel
      - angular:angular
    depends_on:
      - laravel
      - angular
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=app.lo, portal.app.lo , api.app.lo, shop.app.lo  

  database:
    build: ./laravel/docker/mariadb
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_USER=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=homestead"
    ports:
      -  3306:3306

  mongodb:
   image: mongo:latest
   container_name: mongo
   restart: always
   volumes:
     -  mongo:/data/db
   ports:
      - 27017:27017
   command: --storageEngine wiredTiger

  cache:
    image: redis:4.0-alpine
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
  nodejs:
    build: ./laravel/docker/nodejs
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/laravel

volumes:
  mysqldata:
  mongo:

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Nginx vhost configuration

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    server_name app.lo;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://angular:3000;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/laravel/public;
    client_max_body_size 32M;
    server_name  portal.app.lo api.app.lo shop.app.lo; 

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
          try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass laravel:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you just simply startup the angular app on your local developement environment? The problem states, that there is a serialization of Angular in-app object to a json string, but it fails becasoue there are two-way references of objects in it. If you load it up in developement mode, you might see where the problem comes from.

Comment: Startup in a local development environment is working fine. No issues on that. I think the issue is related to this github issue  https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/941#issuecomment-383478644

Comment: Are you using AoT compilation? That can also be the [source of some problems](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#metadata-restrictions)

Comment: Yes! But i have tested in local environment. Everything seems to be fine with or without prod build.

Comment: hm... strange. What happens if you do an image but start up the server inside it manually? What happens, if you start up the app in the docker container in development mode?

Comment: I am able to replicate the issue in my local. This is happening when change the api URL to unreachable  URL

Answer (score -1):

This is due to firewall rules . Running below command solves the issue

```
sudo ufw allow http 
sudo ufw allow https
```

For more details check the [github issue](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/941#issuecomment-383478644)